# Google analytics gatag.js not working in chrome extension manifest v3

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-analytics-4, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Google tag (gatag.js) not triggering events in chrome extension manifest v3.

I have downloaded gatag.js and copied inside the chrome extension and included inside the popup.html

```
  function gtag () { dataLayer.push(arguments) }
  gtag('js', new Date())
  gtag('config', 'G-XXXXX', {
    debug_mode: true,
  })
```

The same thing works when tried in localhost webpage.
Any hints on getting it working in manifest v3.